How to disable login menu ins spring-boot oauth
Is it possible to disable login-menu, which explained [here|https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-oauth2-login] and a lot of another places.
It looks like

And I want to autoredirect on each path depends on client-id.
In my gateway yaml I have
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: ${keycloak-uri}
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
        registration:
          first-client:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: first-client
            scope: openid
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
          second-client:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: second-client
            scope: openid
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code

  jmx:
    enabled: false
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
      - TokenRelay=
      routes:
      - id: first-client-path
        uri: ${first-client.uri}
        order: 120
        predicates:
        - Path=/first/**
      - id: second-client-path
        uri: ${second-client.uri}
        order: 130
        predicates:
          - Path=/second/**

So, I want if I open something like
localhost:8080/**first**/id=3123

it goes to first-client auth-server
when
localhost:8080/**second**/id=3123

it goes to another

i think you should define a custom resolver to override default behavior, then register the resolver in your securitywebfilterchain . check this issue that i think is kind of related to your problem and i believe would have some examples on how to set up a custsom resolver for your case.
Link : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4911
you will have to make some sort of check like
`private String determineClientIdFromPath(String path) {
        if (path.startsWith("/first/")) {
            return "first-client";
        } else if (path.startsWith("/second/")) {
            return "second-client";
        }
        return null;
    }`

, then use this in the resolve method, and finally will be used to map each authRequest to the new resolver . add the "/first" and "/second" to the allowed paths in Security Configuration class too .
